# Can I create a template or doctype for my blog site?

Tags: custom-field

I am new to wordpress, but I know other cms system like umbraco or orchard.

Say I want to do a blog site, in umbraco or orchard, I can add a custom field (e.g. main image), and in the layout design, I can decide where to put that image (either by mvc or some layout file). So later when I add blogs, I don't need to worry where the image should go.

In wordpress, is this kind of function available? Can someone point me to a right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sort of thing is available. It is a custom field.

There are custom fields built into WordPress but I would suggest using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). You can add your custom field for pages, and then create a custom page template and add the custom field output into it. Then to add the custom field into the pcustom page template you can use the `<?php the_field($field_name, $post_id); ?>`. There is more documentation for that on there [website](http://%3C?php%20the_field($field_name,%20$post_id);%20?%3E).